# Why did Seq.replicate disappear?

Tags: .net, f#

I was happily using `Seq.replicate`, `Seq.rev` and other List, Array, and Sequence APIs. Then I installed a couple of packages and some of the APIs, like `Seq.replicate` stopped working. If I hover with the mouse pointer over `Seq.replicate` I see a tooltip saying `The value, constructor, namespace, or type 'replicate' is not defined`.

I checked that `replicate`, `rev` and other functions I can no longer call did not exist in previous versions of `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections`. So maybe the packages I installed forced a change to an older version. I tried to edit the file `package.config` and remove the packages I installed recently (`MathNet.Numerics.FSharp` and `MathNet.Numerics`) but that did not solve the problem.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Maybe you're indeed referencing an older version of FSharp.Core? 1. Check if you get back these functions in an brand new solution. 2. If necessary nuget FSharp.Core and/or use bindig redirects with paket. You can specifiy version number as well in paket.dependencies.

Comment: I was using NuGet. I recreated the whole solution using Paket and now everything is working. Still not sure on what was the problem.

Comment: it's a bit difficult to say, but in many cases packages will target some lowest version they can run on. So there will be some reference somewhere to Fsharp 3.1 for example. Nuget will pick it up and download that FSharp.Core, confusing the whole solution. Paket tends to handle binding redirects and versions in a more stable way.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a good reference to read about packages, NuGet, Paket and related topics? I am flying in the dark.

Comment: Well, both [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) and [Nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/) have a homepage, but unless you're a package author not sure how useful it is. Paket basically wraps nuget and makes easier to manage packages in complex solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Did one of the Nuget packages install an old `FSharp.Core`, which has replaced the default FSharp.Core you were using (not from Nuget)?

Try checking in the Nuget package manager to see if there's an updated `FSharp.Core` (4.1.something) that you can install to replace the older one that's been added to your project.